# Is this definition of reducibility of polynomials correct?

Tags: polynomials, definition

I read the following definition of polynomial reudcibility:

> Let $A$ be one of the sets $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f\in A[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We say that $f$ is reducible over $A$ if $\exists g, h \in A[X]$, $\operatorname{deg}g, \operatorname{deg}h<n$, such that $f=g h$.

This definition puzzles me. I know that $f=2X+2=2(X+1)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is reducible, but, correct me if I am wrong, it should be irreducible according to this definition.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, in this definition it is (probably) assumed that $g,h$ then have *positive* degree, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016802/reducible-and-irreducible-polynomials-are-confusing-me) for a similar question.

So the correct definition should be as follows.

**Definition:** An element $f$ in a commutative ring $R$ with $1$ is called *irreducible* if it is non-zero, not a unit and if from each representation $f=gh$ with $g,h\in R$ always follows that $g$ or $h$ is a unit. Otherwise $f$ is called *reducible*.

**Example:** Let $R=\Bbb Z[X]$ and $f=2X+2$. Then $f$ is reducible, since $2$ is not a unit in $R$. Note that $R^{\times}=\Bbb Z^{\times}=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624987/589